# mysql workbench 6.3.6 crashing mac os x el capitan 10.11.4

Tags: mysql, macos

Please Help. This is a problem report from Mysql Workbench:

```
Process:               MySQLWorkbench [1147]
Path:                  /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/MacOS/MySQLWorkbench
Identifier:            com.oracle.mysql.workbench
Version:               6.3.6.CE (1)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           MySQLWorkbench [1147]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2016-04-24 18:57:35.805 +0400
OS Version:            Mac OS X 10.11.4 (15E65)
Report Version:        11
Anonymous UUID:        D52EFF07-B0AE-E546-2C58-965DB2D0333F

Sleep/Wake UUID:       3316A0B1-778B-4932-B99D-E9514235658E

Time Awake Since Boot: 9900 seconds
Time Since Wake:       4200 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x00000000000000b0
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

VM Regions Near 0xb0:
--> 
    __TEXT                 0000000107696000-0000000107718000 [  520K] r-x/rwx SM=COW  /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/MacOS/MySQLWorkbench
```

Comment: Can you run WB with --log-level=debug3 argument and provide link to log file (you can find it by clicking on menu Help->Locate Log File)?

Answer (score 0):

My friend had a similar error on windows 10. the pid or process id was clashing as both her wamp server and mysql workbench had pid =3306. So I uninstalled it and reinstalled and chaged the pid to 3307 and then it worked fine. Not sure about mac but you could try this. and please comment if it works for you too.

The option to change the pid comes during installation to read carefully everytime before clicking next.

Comment: Thank you for answer, but this doesn't solve my problem